# Making new array and push there keys on that new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of an object array

```
var list = {

Achievement: ["110", "100", "104", "110"],

Emp Code : ["1000001", "1000001", "1000001", "1000001"],

Product :["Product A ", "Product B", "Product A ", "Product B"],

Reportee Name :["Harry", "Harry", "Peter", "Peter"],

Target : ["116", "94", "105", "114"],

percentage: ["94.82758621", "106.3829787", "99.04761905", "96.49122807"]

}
```

and the array I want that is  mention below. Where key item should be the part of array.

```
var list = {

0: ["Achievement","110", "100", "104", "110"],

1 : ["Emp Code","1000001", "1000001", "1000001", "1000001"],

2 :["Product" ,"Product A ", "Product B", "Product A ", "Product B"],

3 :["Reportee Name","Harry", "Harry", "Peter", "Peter"],

4 : ["Target","116", "94", "105", "114"],

5: ["percentage","94.82758621", "106.3829787", "99.04761905", "96.49122807"]

}
```

Comment: What prevents you from coding the solution to your problem?

Comment: var result = Object.keys(list).map((key) => { return this.state.newArray[key] });    what should I add in my code

Comment: Give a try. Play around with for loop

Comment: `return this.state.newArray(key, ...list[key]) `

Comment: Object key name cannot have a space in between also the expected result is not an array but it is an object so why you are using `map` method

Comment: @chetankumar please complete your post not by commenting it but by editing it. And make a proper post, here you introduce `this.state...` from nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `.reduce()` method:

```js
let data = {'Achievement': ["110", "100", "104", "110"],'Emp Code' : ["1000001", "1000001", "1000001", "1000001"],'Product' :["Product A ", "Product B", "Product A ", "Product B"],'Reportee Name' :["Harry", "Harry", "Peter", "Peter"],'Target' : ["116", "94", "105", "114"],'percentage': ["94.82758621", "106.3829787", "99.04761905", "96.49122807"]};

let result = Object.keys(data)
                   .reduce((a, c, i) => (a[i] = [c, ...data[c]], a), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You served the coffee. ^1

Comment: https://jsperf.com/423432423

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Why do you need an object with indexes like an array?  Array solution:

```js
let list = {'Achievement': ["110", "100", "104", "110"],'Emp Code' : ["1000001", "1000001", "1000001", "1000001"],'Product' :["Product A ", "Product B", "Product A ", "Product B"],'Reportee Name' :["Harry", "Harry", "Peter", "Peter"],'Target' : ["116", "94", "105", "114"],'percentage': ["94.82758621", "106.3829787", "99.04761905", "96.49122807"]};

let result = []
for (let key in list) {
  result.push([key, ...list[key]])
}

console.log(result)
```